# Spelling error in duplicate Cover Letter warning

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, spelling

This is a one character spelling error that should be super easy fix.

Careers saves the previous cover letter and brings it up when I apply to another job.  It also throws a useful warning:

> This cover letter is identical to another that you send.

present-tense "send" should actually be past-tense "sent".

[image: Cover Letter is Identical To Another That you Send]

Comment: Personally, I think it would be better as '_will send_'. I mean come on, it's the truth.

Comment: should be `...that you HAVE SENT...`, but i'd ask the english.stackexchange.com people to chime in..

Comment: @iight +1.. Even I felt it should be "you have sent".

Comment: "have sent" sounds right to me. Will check with @WillCole and fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report Michael. This should be fixed now.

Comment: thank you, Epic Beard Man.