# Offer vs. Offered: Tense discrepancy on bounty badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, grammar

The description for [Promoter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/62/promoter) says

> First bounty you offer on your own question.

The description for [Investor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/investor) says (emphasis mine)

> First bounty you offer**ed** on another person's question.

Could the two descriptions match in tense (i.e. either "offered" for both or "offer" for both)?

Comment: I hope this isn't too nitpicky, though [there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113665/fix-badge-overview-page-to-use-proper-grammar) [are](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181533/1-times-badge-list-typo?rq=1) [precedents](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160441/spelling-error-in-duplicate-cover-letter-warning).

Comment: Maybe you earn the "promoter" bage when you are offering a bounty on your own question, but the "investor: badge you only earn after you offered the bounty :-)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Oh, not more conjugations. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We edited some of the badge descriptions recently, looks like this one was not changed - an oversight.

With you in the next build.